How can I install a booting screen on Arch?
I am a very long term Ubuntu-based OS users, and I immensely appreciate the time Canonical and other distributions put into have aesthetically pleasing boot screens (no shame in other distributions that don't have one!).

Is it possible to manually install these upon other distros, such as Arch?

The software package that's responsible for those screens in Fedora/RHEL and Debian/Ubuntu is named plymouth.
Apparently it is available for Arch too. ArchWiki has pretty detailed instructions on how to use it.
